# if/else statements for school project

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm just starting to learn C++ for school, and I'm having trouble completing a school project requiring the use of if/else statements. The project requires code that works as:
[example of working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xOmB.png)
My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int ontime;
int zip;
int work;

int main()

{
cout << "Welcome to the DIG3873 System." << endl;
cout << "Did the student submit the exam on time (Y/N)? ";
cin >> ontime;

if (ontime == 'Y' || 'y') {
    cout << "Did the student zip the file (Y/N)? ";
    cin >> zip;

    if (zip == 'Y' || 'y') {
        cout << "Did the student's code work as requested (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> work;

        if (work == 'Y' || 'y') {
            cout << "Congratulations, YOU PASS. "<< endl;
        } else if (work == 'N' || 'n') {
            cout << "YOU FAIL " << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Please enter a valid response. " << endl;
        }
    } else if (zip == 'N' || 'n') {
        cout << "YOU FAIL " << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Please enter a valid response. " << endl;
    }
} else if (ontime == 'N' || 'n') {
    cout << "YOU FAIL " << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Please enter a valid response. " << endl;
}
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not working as I would have hoped. When it runs, it lets me answer the first statement, then just drops all the other cout statements and a bunch of "YOU FAIL"s and ends the program. We haven't learned anything beyond if/else statements, so I was pretty lost looking at similar coding issues where people recommended using loops instead. Sorry for such a beginner's issue with not understanding if/else statements, thanks!

Comment: `if (ontime == 'Y' || 'y') {` must be changed to `if (ontime == 'Y' || ontime ==  'y') {`, you can't do comparisons as you wrote, they don't work as you expected.

Comment: Obviously you want to learn from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn the language basics.

Comment: I'm trying to find a duplicate, but in the meantime: `if (ontime == 'Y' || 'y')` means "if ontime is `Y` or if `y`"; that is, `'y'` is evaluated as a separate condition, which is always true.

Comment: do yourself a favour and write code in small steps and do testing. You could have noticed that there is something wrong with only the very first `if` in your code. Its is much easier to test and debug little code than it is to test and debug lots of code

Comment: In general you shouldn't use `cin >>` for user input. If you have to use `>>`, always check whether it succeeded: `if (cin >> ontime) { /* ok */ } else { /* something went wrong, ontime is not set */ }`

Comment: You should convert the character to upper case or lower case before comparing.  See `tolower` and `toupper`.  Something like `ontime = tolower(ontime); if (ontime == 'y')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `zip == 'Y' || 'y'` will *always* be `true`.

That's because the only comparison that's made is `zip == 'Y'`. The expression is really `(zip == 'Y') || ('y')`. That is, you test if `zip` is equal to `'Y'`; Or if `'y'`, just `'y'`, no comparison or anything. And since `'y'` is non-zero it's true.

You need to explicitly compare `zip` with *both* values: `zip == 'Y' || zip == 'y'`.

The same is valid for your other conditions as well.

---

You also have another problem, and that is you not actually reading *characters* but integers. If you have `int` variables and are using the formatted input operator `>>`, the input will attempt to parse the input as an integer.

To read *characters* you need to use `char`.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, after fixing that issue throughout the code, now no matter what I type in for the first response the code spits back out "Please enter a valid response"

Comment: @Olivia Think about the *types* you attempt to read. Updated my answer.